# Using redis to cache user data

Tags: laravel, redis

I am building a web application for an online exam using Laravel. I have it like this: very time the user clicks an answer, it queries the DB an saves it. The answers are in a string format e.g. "a, b, e, c" and so on. Now because once the app is deployed on VPS, it will be used concurrently by MANY users. My prediction will be a peak of 500 users at the same time. 
I thought of saving the answer in redis cache first, then saving it to DB once the exam is finished. Would this be a great approach to reduce server load? Is it possible to use redis like that? What else that is simple and implementable that I can do? Thank you.

Comment: Why not using session instand ?

Comment: Because user has the ability to log out and still continue the exam. With session, once user logs out, it gets destroyed.

Comment: I dont think store answer in redis be the better way. Store directly to database will be better than using Redis in your contexte I think.

Comment: @Goms why is that?

Comment: Because storing data from Redis will require a lot of RAM, regardless of whether you're saying that this data is persistent —someone can log out, but on their way back, find their answers —. Apart from the intense use of RAM memory, its data must finally be persisted again in the database; All this to avoid the number of queries in the database. Did you really think it's the best way instand of store datas directly to database ?

Comment: @Goms where are you getting the info from? How much is lots of RAM? I got this directly from https://redis.io/topics/faq

`What's the Redis memory footprint?

To give you a few examples (all obtained using 64-bit instances):

    An empty instance uses ~ 3MB of memory.
    1 Million small Keys -> String Value pairs use ~ 85MB of memory.
    1 Million Keys -> Hash value, representing an object with 5 fields, use ~ 160 MB of memory.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. it's better to used session and session store into the redis for reduce your server load.
2. if you don't want to any server load then used cookie and store into the user browser so no any server side load there.

Comment: Im avoiding any client storage atm. Just preventive measures if users clear their browser data. Had so